# How to deploy django on VPS with external subdomain.?

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain

Good day.
I have a web app that I have developed using django. I tested fine on my local, and I'm happy with how it works.
However I'm facing an issue bringing it online I used those two guides to reach my deployment:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

and

- http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

However my page is giving me a forbidden page.

I suspect my issue is with the way I'm handling the subdomain. So the site . has been developed using php, and I have worked on my part with django and been provided with a subdomain which is member.domain.com, So I'm deploying it on the VPS and have to make it use the subdomain.

This is how my allowed hosts looks in the settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['member.domain.com']
```

and

in my nginx:

```
    upstream app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/path/project/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name member.domain.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/path/project/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/path/project/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/path/project/src/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/path/project/src/media/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page  502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/path/project/src/static/;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

## To respond to 'example.com' and any subdomains, start the domain with a dot

## ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com', '203.0.113.5']

I didn't even try how to run django on subdomains, but from article link you shared, you missed some configuration in your settings.py

## ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['member.domain.com']

Changed

## ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.domain.com']

Hope this will solve your problem